# How to limit the character range in regular expression?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Lets say,

```
let sentence= "Dear user {#val#}{#val#} thanks"
```

{#val#} is the dynamic value in the above sentence. Here in place of {#val#}, there can be any values but atleast 0 and maximum 5 characters can be there. So  I'm substituting the {#val#} as .{0,5} . I dont need to consider spaces except for the {#val#} portion, so my formed regex would be,

```
let regex =  /^Dear\s*user\s*.{0,5}.{0,5} thanks$/i
let customermsg = "Dear user 1 2 thanks" //Should be valid
let customermsg1 = "Dear user 12345 6789 thanks" //Should be valid
let customermsg2 = "Dear user 123 5 6789 thanks" //Should be valid because space can also be considered as a character and for fist .{0,5} => 123 5 and for second .{0,5} => 6789
let customermsg3 = "Dear user 1 thanks" //Should pass 
let customermsg4 = "Dea r user 1 tha nks" // Should Pass since spaces are not considered in the static portion.
```

but when I try to test using below,

```
 regex.test(customermsg)
```

Its quite opposite. Even I have tried the below,

```
let splitters=/{\\#val\\#}|((\\s\*))/gi;
sentence = sentence.replace(splitters, (x, y) => y ? y : ".(\\S{0,5})");
```

This returns the regex as,

```
 /^Dear\s*user\s*.(\S{0,5}).(\S{0,5})\s*thanks$/
```

But this is also not working as expected. I'm stuck on this. Please help me.

Comment: Perhaps like this `^Dear\s*user\s*\S.{1,4}.{1,5} thanks$` https://regex101.com/r/cJdQOk/1

Comment: Are the spaces around Dear and user optional? In your last example the first space after user is being matched by `.{1,5}`. So you might just try `/^Dear\s+user\s+.{1,5}.{1,5} thanks$/i`

Comment: @Khauri Yeah yes, the spaces around Dear and user are optional. There can be many spaces or may not be spaces around Dear and User. So I will not be able to use \s+ snce it will limit the option to single space. Please suggest.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Is there any way  that  we can substitute same values for both the {#val#} {#val#} ? Kindly provide your input..

Comment: And val is allowed to start with spaces as well?

Comment: @Khauri After user there can be spaces,but val is not allowed to start with space, in between val there can be spaces whcih will again be counted as a character.. For example 12 45 12 45 can be there in place {#val#}{#val#}

Comment: @sasi I have added an answer with 2 examples that will use `{#val#}{#val#}` in the replacement. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @sasi is there something that is not allowed between 2 values? multiple empty strings? By the way, as we see from answers and people contributing to it, with every answer we are aware of something else which is demanded, meaning your question is having quite a few holes in it...

Comment: This question is not clear. It should be absolutely clear where spaces can or cannot occur, what the other characters are supposed to be, ...etc. What needs to be captured and what not,... There is too much ambiguity here.

Comment: @trincot Here {#val#} is the dynamic content. 1) In place of val there can 0 to 5 chars including space. 2) If two {#val#} continuously comes together without space , max character can be 10 including space. 3) If two val comes together with a space means, max character can be 11 including the space. 4) For other portion spaces doesn't matter. That means in customer send msgs, they might give space within a word like "De ar", but still without considering the space, both the sentences should be matched. Is it understandable? Kindly let me know.

Comment: @thefourthbird No, it didnt work..

Comment: @sasi Perhaps like this? https://regex101.com/r/CZkvKl/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Even sentence = sentence.replace(splitters, (x, y) => y ? y : "(?=\\S).{0,5})"); and what you have provided also I have tried.. it is accepting more than 10 characters when simultaneously {val} has been given with space.. Even space between De ar doesn't work also fine, but substituting 10 chars is not even working for me.. please help

Comment: I don't see any rule in your question about the very first character that belongs to val1. What can it be? What about the last character of val1, and of the first of val2, and of the last of val2? What if 6 characters can match for val1 & val2, what will determine where val1 stops and val2 begins? Any rules about non-alphanumerical characters, like punctuation, line feeds,...? Can val1 consist of *only* spaces? Same for val2... Can any number of spaces come *before* val1, or *after* val2?

Comment: @trincot before val1 should not start with space and there is no limit where val1 should stop .. any character can be there or special char can be there in space of val...

Comment: What does that mean "before val1 should not start with space". Do you mean no spaces *before*, or val1 does not *start* with space? What about all the other questions I asked? *"There is no limit where val1 should stop"*: then what decides where it stops? Just random?

Comment: @trincot at start if it have spaces, that will not be considered in the count(0,5) ,  if two val comes together, it should be within the limit of 10, that's it.. there is no decider where it should stop..

Comment: This is the first time I read about a limit of 20. Seems like this question is getting more ambiguous instead of less. Can you answer also: What about conditions on the last character of val1, and of the first of val2, and of the last of val2? Can any of those be a space?

Comment: @trincot Sorry, it should be 10, it's a typo.. In between val there can be spaces and it is counted. For example if two val continuously there {val}{val} , value can be 0 to 10 , fr example: 1234 56789 is valid. Here count is 10 and it is valid. If {val} {val} I mean val space val is there, count can be upto 11 digits. 12345 67890 is valid. From 0 it can be upto 10 if val dnt have spaces, it can be upto 11 if val contains spaces..

Comment: What about `123456 78`, `12 345678`, or with 2 spaces in between: `12345  67890`? Are all these invalid? What about `th ththanks` without space before "thanks"... is that allowed? And `dearusererer ererthanks`... should that be OK?

Comment: @trincot 123456 78 allowed,  1234567  8 (double spaces allowed and counted) .. without space thanks allowed. Yes it is ok..

Comment: So what is val1 in `123456 78`?

Comment: @trincot we need not worry about that sir. If the count is within the limit, that's enough for us ..

Comment: So, do I understand correctly that *one* space will not be counted, but a second space *is* counted? So that `01234567890` (11 chars) is not OK, but `0123456 789` (11 chars, including 1 space) is OK, while `0123  456789` (12 chars, including 2 spaces) is not OK. Correct?

Comment: @trincot first val first space can not be counted. 11 chars is ok when two val comes with space, {val} {val} in this case 01234567890 is ok & also 123456789 0 is also ok. 12 chars is never ok. If two val comes together without space, then max limit is only 10. Single or double space may come, but is also counted as a number, for example, 123<space><space>567 can come and the count is 8 and it is valid..

Comment: So then `01234567890` is not OK. I think you made a mistake when you wrote that it is ok. It is 11 characters without space.

Comment: @trincot No sir, if {val} {val} is there in the defined sentence, maxchar length is 11, either it can be with space or without space Sir, so in that case it is allowed.

Comment: But you wrote *"If two val comes together without space, then max limit is only 10"* ??? And this `01234567890` is without space, so then max limit is 10... or is it 11? I am amazed that we have to have such a long conversation for getting the specification right.

Comment: Can you clarify when exactly the limit is 11 and when it is 10? It is not clear. There is a contradiction in what you wrote above. Your question does not mention this aspect at all. You should edit it. Please add several positive and negative examples of strings with 10 and 11 characters at that dynamic spot.

Comment: Have a look at this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/Bf8WlK/1) and the examples that match and don't match. This rejects `01234567890` because by the rule *"If two val comes together without space, then max limit is only 10"* it exceeds the limit. It this should not be rejected, then please give examples of strings of 11 characters that *should* be rejected, and why.

Comment: @trincot There is a sentence defined in db, using single {#val#} or multiple or many {#val#} s . For ex, "Dear {#val#}, thanks {#val#}{#val#}.. Customer would send a sentence where in place of {#val}, they might substitute different value and send , for that the ruleset is like, it should be within the range of 0,5. It two Val's are defined continuosly in db together, the limit should be 10 in the customer sent msg, if two Val's are given space in between in db, them the limit should be 11..

Comment: @trincot I'm trying to form a regex for the sentence which is defined in db and trying to compare with the customer sent msg..

Comment: Did you check my regex proposal?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to check if a *number* and *white spaces* are present multiple times according to

> "Dear user 1 thanks" //Should fail since only one value is there

So, your regex is fine, except that it doesn't check if a *number* and *white spaces* are present *more than one* times.

Use the following regex

```
Dear\s*user\s*([\d]+[\s]+){2,5}\s*thanks$
```

- `([\d]+[\s]+){2,5}\s*`

  - Capturing group matching *digit* between zero and unlimited times and *white space* between zero and unlimited times, for atleast two times and max five.

The `([\d]+[\s]+){2,5}\s*` part makes it sure that a number is present atleast two times, so a single number in the string `Dear user ... thanks` will fail.

You can use as many *white spaces* before, between and after the digits as you please.

```js
let regex =  /Dear\s*user\s*([\d]+[\s]+){2,5}\s*thanks$/i
let customermsg = "Dear user 1 2 thanks" //Should be valid
let customermsg1 = "Dear user 12345 6789 thanks" //Should be valid
let customermsg2 = "Dear user 123 5 6789 thanks" //Should be valid because space can also be considered as a character and for fist .{1,5} => 123 5 and for second .{1,5} => 6789
let customermsg3 = "Dear user 1 thanks" //Should fail since only one value is there
let customermsg4 = "Dear user   435 4523 thanks" // With many spaces

console.log(regex.test(customermsg));
console.log(regex.test(customermsg1));
console.log(regex.test(customermsg2));
console.log(regex.test(customermsg3));
console.log(regex.test(customermsg4));
```

Comment: Thank you but after user there can be space or can have more spaces or may not have space. Thats where we have the problem. Could you pls help?

Answer (score 1):

https://regex101.com/r/qBFSxq/1

This can be one way of solving it: `^Dear\s*user(\s*\d)?(?(1)(.{1,5})(?=(\s{1,}))(?<!(\s{2}))(.{1,5}) thanks|\s*thanks)$`

Edit: added regex positive lookahead construct (`(.{1,5})(?=(\s{1,}))`), https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html, as well as using conditionals inside regex (`(\s*\d)?(?(1)...`) and negative lookbehind (`(?<!(\s{2}))(.{1,5})`)

Comment: Thanks but  "Dear user 12345 64789 thanks" it should be invalid.  Its m0re than 10 characters including the spaces in between . But it also becomes valid if i try this. Is there any other way. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You could use s capture group for the part before the match, and start the match with a single non whitespace char.

Assert 1-9 chars at the right followed by  `thanks`. If that is the case, match at least another non whitespace char followed by the rest until you reach  `thanks`.

For example

```js
let regex = /^(Dear\s*user\s*)\S(?=.{1,9} thanks$)\s*\S.*(?= thanks$)/i;
[
  "Dear user 1 2 thanks",
  "Dear user 12345 6789 thanks",
  "Dear user 123 5 6789 thanks",
  "Dear user 1    thanks",
  "Dear user 1 thanks"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(s.replace(regex, (m, g1) => g1 + "{#val#}{#val#}"))
);
```

Or if there can be only digits and spaces with a single capture group

```js
let regex = /^(Dear\s*user\s*)\d(?=[ \d]*\d)[ \d]{1,9}(?= thanks$)/i;
[
  "Dear user 1 2 thanks",
  "Dear user 12345 6789 thanks",
  "Dear user 123 5 6789 thanks",
  "Dear user 1 thanks",
  "Dear user 1    thanks",
  "Dear user 12345 64789 thanks"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(s.replace(regex, (m, g1) => g1 + "{#val#}{#val#}"))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it you want

- Both vals to be replaced by the same regex
- Spaces before the val to be ignored
- Spaces to be part of the val

And also

- val cannot start with a space

The first point is the trickiest because you need to ensure that the first value does not start with a space while the second value can, yet still be the same regex. Essentially you have two different requirements here.

The only solution I can think of is to do a lookahead to ensure that the next character after the optional spaces after user is a non-space character.

```js
/^Dear\s*user\s*(?=\S)(.{1,5}.{1,5}) thanks$/
```

https://regex101.com/r/AtUxDS/2

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I've completely understood your requirements but if you wish to allow whitespace between any of the letters you can do something like this:

`^\s*D\s*e\s*a\s*r\s*u\s*s\s*e\s*r\s*(?:.\s*){0,5}\s*(?:.\s*){0,5}\s*t\s*h\s*a\s*n\s*k\s*s\s*$`

**Explanation:** `\s*` is placed before and after every letter to allow whitespace. For the character ranges, `(?:.\s*){0,5}` is used to allow whitespace after each counted character. (The `?:` at the start excludes it as a capturing group.)

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/2ZAqui/1